# Remove files older than 30 days without using find, using a shell script

Tags: linux, bash

I have been looking for quite a while for an answer to this.

My hosting environment will not let me use the find command. Is there a way to search a directory for all files older than 30 days and delete/rm them? Any reading or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Download GNU findutils and compile find yourself. http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/findutils/

Comment: Or find a new hosting environment, that's a pretty absurd limitation.

Comment: Read `man stat` to get the mtime of your files. If you want to get files recursively, and your provider lets you use bash, enable the `globstar` shell option: `stat -c "%Y %n' **`

Comment: Can you use one of these Perl solutions?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24810615/perl-script-to-remove-files-older-than-a-year

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
touch -d 'now -30 days' reference_file
for f in *; do
    if [ "$f" -ot reference_file ]; then
        rm "$f"
    fi
done
```

Or is `touch` also on the blacklist?

Comment: Thanks. This appears to have worked with some slight modification. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

awk to the rescue!

if it's for a single directory, you can feed the formatted time stamp from `ls` to a simple awk script to do the filtering

```
 ls -lt --time-style="+%Y %m %d %H %M %S" | awk '{ts=mktime($6 " " $7 " " $8 " " $9 " " $10 " " $11)} ts<systime()-30*24*60*60'
```